# Why is puts() function not printing mutiple output in client-server socket code?

Tags: c++, sockets, puts

Here is my client-server code which works only for a single user at a time and the client can send as many messages as he wants.

I show the received message at the server and its reply (which is actually reverse of it) - and also the message "message sent".

At client side I show the input message and the server reply: "message got"

But there is a problem in my code: when I try to send multiple messages I get the right output at server side but not at client side, which is only "message got", but after that puts function it doesn't print any output to std-out.

I have tried many things but I haven't found a way to do it.

Is there any flushing to std-out or am I missing something?
Please tell me.

```
server code::::::  
    #include <stdio.h>  
    #include <string.h>   
    #include <sys/socket.h>  
    #include <arpa/inet.h>     
    #include <unistd.h>   
    #include <stdlib.h>  
    int main(int argc , char *argv[])  
{  
     int socket_desc , client_sock , c , read_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    char client_message[2000];


    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    //Prepare the sockaddr_in structure
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons( 42969 );

    //Bind
    if( bind(socket_desc,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        //print the error message
        perror("bind failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("bind done");

    //Listen
    listen(socket_desc , 3);

    //Accept and incoming connection
    puts("Waiting for incoming connections...");
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
     while(1)
    {
    //accept connection from an incoming client
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c);
    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }
    puts("Connection accepted");
    pid_t p=fork();
      if(p==0)
     {
       close(socket_desc);
    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(client_sock , client_message , sizeof(client_message) , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        puts(client_message);   
    char message[20000];
    int i,j=0;
    for(i=strlen(client_message)-1;i>=0;i--)
    message[j++]=client_message[i];
       message[j]='\0';
puts(message);
        //Send the message back to client
       if( send(client_sock , message , sizeof(message),0)>0)
                   puts("message sent");
       // memset(client_message,'\0',sizeof(client_message));
     //memset(message,'\0',sizeof(message));
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }
close(client_sock);
exit(1);
}
}
      close(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}




client code::::

#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h> 
#include<sys/socket.h> 
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
   // char message[1000] ,
    char server_reply[2000];

    //Create socket
    sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (sock == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }
    puts("Socket created");

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons (42969 );

    //Connect to remote server
    if (connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        perror("connect failed. Error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");

    //keep communicating with server
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter message : ");
     char message[1000];
        scanf("%s" , message);
        //Send some data
        if( send(sock , message , sizeof(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }

        //Receive a reply from the server
        if( recv(sock , server_reply , sizeof(server_reply) , 0) > 0)
        {
            puts("message got");

        }

        puts("Server reply :");
        puts(server_reply);
fflush(stdout);
 //memset(server_reply,'\0',sizeof(server_reply));
     // memset(message,'\0',sizeof(message));
    }

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the formatting of your code is hard to read, could you improve it?

Comment: i have explained it...above the code section(input and outputat server and client).....and all other things in code section are simple tcp-socket function.....if there any problem in any section to understand...plz mention that....              my question is why it is not printing reply at client side in case of sending more than one time messages(however message has sent to server and server has also sent reply).....for single message it is printing outout right ..but not in case of more than one time

Comment: I don't understand what works wrong ??? I've tried your code and all works correctly. I've done this in the Linux, Red Hat 6.5 ....................and......................Why you are putting message inversely at the server side ????

Comment: Your comments say that you receive a "message" and send a "message", but then you call send and receive functions on a TCP connection, which don't send or receive messages. If you want to send and receive messages, you have to write code to send and receive messages, which you have not done. So if this works, it does so purely by luck. TCP is a byte stream protocol, not a message protocol. If you want a message protocol, you have to implement one.

Comment: for which purpose i should use send-receive tcp socket function....i have sent messages that's actually is a stream of bytes isn't it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem at this place in server side code:

```
   if( send(client_sock , message , sizeof(message),0)>0)
               puts("message sent");
```

You must replace:

```
   if( send(client_sock , message , strlen(message) + 1,0)>0)
               puts("message sent");
```

Comment: your comment helps but can you please explain the syntax of send in tcp...i think it takes 3rd argument as size of ...not the strlen...i m confused with that....tell me ???

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal yes You are right. Third argument is size of data. But in your case you transfer to `send` function actual size of your data.

Answer (score 1):

There are different flaws in this code.

Server side:

- you accept socket `client_sock` in a loop, but only close it in the child: you are leaking socket descriptors -> parent should have also `close(client_sock);`
- client send a message of max size 1000, that server reads in a buffer of size 2000. Fine till here. But you use `strlen` to find the useful part and send back 2000 bytes (meaning you are sending garbage).

Client side:

- you read a string from stdin with scanf into a buffer or size 1000. Ok. But then you send 1000 byte, the message and garbage.
- you have no message delimitation. So first message could need many read (in fact if needs at least 2 since you currently send 2000 bytes and read it by chunks of 1000!)

You are mixing size of buffer, string length, and number of bytes sent/received. In server, you should use the number of bytes received and never output more then it, of *if you know the the message is null terinated*, never output more than its length. And if you want to exchange more than one message, use a delimiting strategy (ending with null (uncommon) or with `\n`, of send first one or 2 bytes containing the size).